# problem about pandas “concat" method merging two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatecate two dataFrames of pandas, but the result does not work in the way I hope. I have tried to set `axis` attribute of `pd.concat` method to `0` and `1` but setting different values of `axis` gives the same wrong result. Here is the problem:
I have a DataFrame `log_prob`:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1

[1 rows x 10 columns]   DataFrame
```

and I concatecate it with another DataFrame `df_prob`:

```
cur_prob = {'0': [0.1], '1': [0.12194750477338884], '2': [0.1], '3': [0.08351573952785551], '4': [0.08870935107708666], '5': [0.07405927410551559], '6': [0.10437898916465049], '7': [0.11847414313078496], '8': [0.0818165135104054], '9': [0.12709848471031268]}
df_prob = pd.DataFrame(cur_prob)
new_prob = pd.concat([log_prob, df_prob])
```

Here I checked the result of `df_prob`:

```
     0         1    2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
0  0.1  0.121948  0.1  0.083516  0.088709  0.074059  0.104379  0.118474  0.081817  0.127098

[1 rows x 10 columns]   DataFrame
```

It has same dimensions with `log_prob`, which is (1x10), as well as identical header names, so I want the resulted `new_prob` to be like:

```
     0         1    2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
0  0.1       0.1  0.1       0.1       0.1       0.1       0.1       0.1       0.1       0.1  
0  0.1  0.121948  0.1  0.083516  0.088709  0.074059  0.104379  0.118474  0.081817  0.127098

[2 rows x 10 columns]   DataFrame
```

However it ***actually*** is like:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0         1    2         3         4         5         0         7         8         9
0  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.1  0.121948  0.1  0.083516  0.088709  0.074059  0.104379  0.118474  0.081817  0.127098

[2 rows x 20 columns]   DataFrame
```

And the result does not change no matter `axis` in `concat` is set to `1` or `0`. What is the reason for the weird result I get?

Comment: one data frame has *integer* column names, the other has *string* column names.

Answer (score 1):

column names are not of the same type. (`int` vs `str`). The concat method is handling them as different columns